# Перемещение персонажа влево, вправо

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть две стенки между ними персонаж, как сделать что бы персонаж сначала перемещался влево, касался стенки и перемещался в сторону правой стенки и так бесконечно. В Unity новичек, пытался завязать с помощью `OnCollision` но не как не мог толком получить ссылку на объект что бы активировать в нем скрипт перемещения вправо или влево. Проект 2D.

Answer (score 1):

Можно например добавить rigibody, отключить гравитацию, отслеживать контакт и применять силу.

Comment: Да, с помощью OnCollision.

Comment: А не подскажите как запустить скрипт, из другого скрипта?

Comment: один вопрос, один ответ :)